# Using IPv6 leads to "suspicious traffic" page when using Google Search

Tags: networking, google-chrome, ipv6, google-search

I have configured IPv6 tunnel provided by https://tunnelbroker.net/ on my router. IPv6 is working perfectly, but now I have another problem: when I try using http://google.com/ it says that suspicious traffic was detected from my network and I have to solve a CAPTCHA. I have checked, my pc does not send any traffic to google.com when I'm not using it. The CAPTCHA is really annoying and I might just force it to use IPv4, but maybe there is another better solution, because the same happens, for example, on http://yandex.ru/.

Comment: It will likely happen anywhere that doesn't like VPN traffic.

Comment: If I get native IPv6 would it be treated the same?

Comment: I've never tried IPv6, it's not common yet in the UK.